# Extra li is showing in angular 2 ngFor

Tags: angular2-directives

I have an array like this : public colors = ['red','green','blue'];

This is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#color of colors; #i=index">{{i}}. {{color}}<li>
</ul>
```

This my output: 
[image]

**Why is this extra list is showing?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it. It was occurring because i wrote `"<li>"` instead of `"</li>"` at the end of the `li` tag